# How to have Heroku Application or iOS App communicate with S3 Server via Bucketeer so images can be saved?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku, parse-server

I have a Heroku Application with a Parse Server deployed remotely on it and fully functional and connected to my iOS App. However, I have a current issue where in my app when a user makes a post, the images only get saved temporarily for 24 hours before disappearing, leaving the posts with a big empty square in the middle where the image normally is. With research, I found that it was due to Heroku's dynos being ephemeral. To fix the issue, I've provisioned and configured Bucketeer into the application so I can have an S3 Bucket that stores the images permanently, however, the issue still stands.

How do I have the Heroku Application or my iOS App communicate with the S3 Bucket so that when a user creates a post the image file gets uploaded and stored in the Bucket so that it doesn't disappear? I've tried looking for an answer in the docs and even in tutorials and nothing.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Github for Backend Server I'm using on Heroku: https://github.com/KingDecorpel12/parse-hipaa